# Masking out parts of video footage so 3D object can appear

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, masking

I have built a residential area in 3D in Blender that appears on some drone footage. The residential area is partially hidden behind some other buildings. I would like to mask out that part.

[image]
*Below the arrow I would like to add a mask in the red square to hide the 3D block of apartments behind the real building*

Comment: Hi Hank, and welcome to Blender SE. You can find the answer here, for Blender Cycles: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7613/create-invisibility-cloak-alpha-mask-material, and here for Blender Internal renderer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33301/invisible-object-that-hides-other-objects-as-a-mask/33846#33846. Cheers!

Comment: Could you please clarify this? I'm not sure if you're trying to mask out video footage, or 3D objects. Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/44397/2843 (actually a duplicate, but no answer yet, though tons of links to similar questions)

Comment: added a picture, hopefully it will clarify any questions.

Comment: @Hank Thanks, makes it much more clear :) Have you looked at the question that this was marked as a duplicate to? Does that help?