# How to use an object to mask out other objects in 3.0?

Tags: materials, transparency, masking

I am trying to figure out how to use a transparent object to mask out other objects.
Other people have asked similar questions, so here's the links to the others I found:

[Create invisibility cloak (alpha mask material)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7613/create-invisibility-cloak-alpha-mask-material?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Invisible object that hides other objects (as a mask)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33301/invisible-object-that-hides-other-objects-as-a-mask)

But I can't figure out how to do it in 3.0 with Eevee, hence the fresh question.

I would appreciate screenshots with an answer because I'm very visual! Thank you.

Comment: What did you try and were you failed? Also your screen case would be helpfull ... provided links can hide one object or all behinde ...

Comment: @vklidu I tried a few things to get the result I wanted (combinations of transparency, backface culling, render layers of various setups) but either way I have an answer now, a holdout node in a material :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several options here:

1. Check holdout option in object settings:

[image]

2. Use a holdout shader:

[image]

3. Turn on holdout toddles in outliner:

[image]

and enable it for specific collections:

[image]

Comment: Thank  you, the Holdout node for a material was exactly what I needed!