# How to use an object to mask objects only in collection?

Tags: transparency, grease-pencil, collections

I reviewed [How to use an object to mask out other objects in 3.0? post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252298/how-to-use-an-object-to-mask-out-other-objects-in-3-0). I'm working in 2D animation, however, this method masks the entire scene. Is there a way to mask only the objects in a collection? See image for actual result, settings, and expected result.
[image: Expected and actual results with settings]

Comment: You could do it with the Compositor if you are familiar with it

Comment: Thanks @moonboots. I'm not familiar with the compositor yet. I think I figured it out by using another grease pencil layer and a holdout material in the target GP objects. My issue is that I'm animating multiple objects on a path where I don't want to see the objects in certain areas of the scene. But when you animate the grease pencil object, you also carry the holdout mask with it instead of a static mask hiding where I want.